# How to optimise the page load when using Active Highchart graph?

Tags: jquery, yii, highcharts

I am using Active Highchart widget in yii framework to generate grahs. The widget renders all plot points in html, due to which the page load takes time. I have minute-wise data to be plot for a 30 hr period. There are 3 such graphs along with 3 bar graphs on one page. It takes few minutes to load. Also many empty span tags can be seen in the view source. Can someone lemme know how it can be optimised?

My code block is as follows

View code:

```
 $this->Widget('ext.ActiveHighcharts.HighchartsWidget', array(
    'dataProvider'=>$interestsDataProvider,
    'template'=>'{items}',
    'options'=> array(
        'exporting'=>array(             //Disable print and export options
            'enabled'=>false,
        ),
        'title'=>array(
            'text'=>'Interests By Min'
        ),
        'xAxis'=>array(
            "categories"=>'date',
            "tickInterval" =>120,

            'labels' => array(

                "enabled"=> true,
                "formatter"=>new 
                CJavaScriptExpression("function() {return setXAxis((this.value))}"),

           ),
        ),
        'yAxis' => array(
            'title' => array('text' => 'Contacts'),
    'max'=>700
        ),
        "tooltip"=>array(
            "formatter"=>new 
        CJavaScriptExpression("function() { return '<b>'+this.series.name +'</b>   <br/>'+setXAxis((this.x))+' Hrs : '+(this.y) ;}"),
        ),
        'plotOptions'=>array(
            'series'=>array(
            'cursor'=> 'pointer', 
             'trackByArea'  =>true,  //Makes graph area clickable    
             'marker'=>array(
                 'enabled'=>false,
             ),
            'events'=> array(
            'click'=>new CJavaScriptExpression("function() {openWindow('interests')}"),
            ),    
            )),
        'series'=>array(
            array(
                'type'=>'area',
                'name'=>$lastWeek,             //title of data
                'dataResource'=>'yesterday',     //data resource according to datebase column
                'fillOpacity'=>0.5,

              ),
             array(
                'type'=>'area',
                'name'=>$today,             //title of data
                'dataResource'=>'today',     //data resource according to datebase column
                'fillOpacity'=>0.5,
                'color'=> '#DC3912',
          ),

        ),


    )
));
```

Comment: Have you tried to to use native highcharts instead of yii wrapper?

Comment: I am trying active highcharts as it directly connects the query result to the graph and thus saving processing time of reading data and converting to json. I have several points to be plot and hence trying out active highcharts.

Comment: Why you cannot use getJSON() to communicate?

Comment: I can use json to pass data, i was trying to explore the widget approach

Comment: Json seems to be more efficient, but you need to test in your own environment.